# Weird Error "error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent()"

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting this error on selecting customer name from manage customer section in magento admin panel

> error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent():
>
> event name: address_country_changed  error message:
>
> cannot read property 'show' of undefined.

Comment: I have the same error, what's the problem ????

Comment: The error description is quite poor. Be more specific, adding page name, and full error report. Next to the error you should have also a reference to the line which is causing it.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error as well and was able to fix it. Below is how I figured it out.

- Open up eav_attribute table through PHPMyAdmin
- Find postcode attribute_code and click edit
- Change is_required from 0 to 1
- Then click go